Two different versions of the same program
I ended up needing to download android studio (AS) multiple times as I downloaded a old version first accidentally. Now whenever I start AS via the terminal ( I type cd /usr/local/android-studio/bin and then bash studio.sh to start it), I start a 2024 version from AS. The right one. But when I search for AS in the searchbar on the bottom of the screen I start a 2022 version.
I obviously would rather want to use the searchbar as it's the normal/easier way.
My assumption is that I have 2 AS on my PC right now. But I have deleted the first one.
This is what gets executed when I click on the icon in the searchbar:
/usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=android-studio com.google.AndroidStudio

Is there maybe some way to find the path that the icon in the searchbar uses, so that I can start the newer 2024 version of the tool?

You can't have deleted the older version if you're successfully starting it from your search bar

No, I still dont know how it is possible that this command starts the 2022 version

I don't see the issue. You've got a Flatpak version (that you don't want) and a locally installed version in /usr/local/android-studio that you do want.

but how can i delete the flatpak version? i dont know where to search for it

How did you install it

I downloaded a tar.gz file and extracted it to the Desktop. But I already deleted that Desktop folder. Thats why I am confused

Downloading and extracting a tar file won't generally do anything it and of itself. Presumably you ran some sort of installation script too?
